# PowerShell V4 - Passing a hashtable to a function

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I'm writing a PowerShell function that will take a hashtable as one of the arguments.

Am I doing something that is bad practice? Secondly, is there a better way of doing it?

Code:

```
function removeItem
{
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$path,

        [string]$writetoText,
        $hashWrite = @{}
    )

}
```

Comment: If your logic requires a hashtable to be passed - go for it. I would consider it a bad practice if you accepted a single hastable parameter where you added various not related commands, but it doesn't seem to be the case here

Comment: You might consider strongly typing that parameter, i.e.  `[hashtable]$HashWrite`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short Answer: No

I can't see any reason why it would be bad practice to use a `[hashtable]` or any other data type as a parameter, at least in a vacuum. If you gave us some idea of what you intended to do with it, then we may be able to tell you a better of way to achieve your goal.

#### Example

If your intention is to pass many related parameters into the function, but they only apply if certain other parameters are present or have certain values, then I would say it's bad practice in PowerShell to simply use a `[hashtable]` for this.

Why? Because you can use [Parameter Sets](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/06/30/use-parameter-sets-to-simplify-powershell-commands/) and [Dynamic Parameters](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2016/10/06/implement-dynamic-parameters.aspx) to do this in a way where the language will support it (by automatically generating help, tab completing values, etc.) and handle much of the validation you would have to write code for.

Comment: I think it would be best to ask another question to fully understand what it is I'm trying to accomplish. Hang on. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Both links are broken. The first redirects to a generic page and the second says *"Oops! That page can’t be found. This page has been disabled."*.

Comment: For the first link: An alternative (or maybe it is the same?) is *[Use Parameter Sets to Simplify PowerShell Commands](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/06/30/use-parameter-sets-to-simplify-powershell-commands/)*.

Comment: For the second link: An alternative may be *[How To Implement Dynamic Parameters in Your PowerShell Functions](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2016/10/06/implement-dynamic-parameters.aspx)* - includes DynamicParam.

Comment: Thanks @PeterMortensen, I've updated using those links. Yu have the rep to edit directly though, if you see anything else like this (at least on my answers) please go ahead and edit it. I definitely welcome the improvement!